# 'value' Property Not Available on 'field' Object When Using React Hook Form with CreatableSelect ReactSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js

I'm using React Hook Form to control forms in my React application. I have a component SelectCreateableInputForm which utilizes React Hook Form to manage input.

```
export const SelectCreateableInput = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, SelectProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { className, value, defaultValue, onChange, onValueChange, ...rest } =
      props;

    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
    const [_value, setValue] = useUncontrolled({
      value,
      defaultValue,
      onChange,
    });

    const handleOnChange = (newValue: unknown) => {
      setValue(newValue);
      onValueChange?.(newValue);
    };

    useEffect(() => setIsMounted(true), []);

    return isMounted ? (
      <CreatableSelect
        {...rest}
        ref={ref as any}
        value={_value}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        styles={customStyles}
        className={cn(className)}
      />
    ) : null;
  }
);

SelectCreateableInput.displayName = 'SelectCreateableInput';
```

```
export function SelectCreateableInputForm({
  form,
  name,
  label,
  withAsterik = true,
  shouldUnregister = true,
  description,
  className,
  error,
  selectProps,
}: SelectFormProps) {
  return (
    <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name={name}
      shouldUnregister={shouldUnregister}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem className={className}>
          <FormLabel withAsterik={withAsterik}>{label}</FormLabel>
          <FormControl>
            {/* posisi selectProps harus setelah field agar onChange jalan */}
            <SelectCreateableInput
              {...selectProps}
              {...field}
              value={field.value}
              onChange={field.onChange}
            />
          </FormControl>
          {JSON.stringify(field.value)}
          <FormDescription>{description && description}</FormDescription>
          <FormMessage>{error && error}</FormMessage>
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Issue Faced: when I change the value (not via input) but from handleChangeVarName here

```
const handleChangeVarName = (value: ValueOnchangeProps, index: number) => {
    if (!value) {
      form.setValue(`variationName.${index}`, {
        label: null,
        value: null,
      });

      console.log('clear!');
      form.setValue(`variationType.${index}`, [
        {
          label: 'tes',
          value: 'null',
          variationName: null,
        },
      ]);

      return;
    }
```

the change in value is not reflected in the other select.

The form still gets its value if i check on react dev tools, but it looks like the value hasn't rendered.

[ERROR DETAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pirMq.png)